# Setting contents of script with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to set the contents of a script element with jQuery? Currently I have:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var s = document.createElement("script");
s.type = "text/javascript";
s.src = "http://somedomain.com/somescri...";
$("head").append(s);
});
```

What if I wanted to replace src property with actual javascript code? Is this possible with jQuery or Javascript?

Comment: ...can't you just, you know, run the code there? What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a better way to write that, using [`$.getScript`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/):

```
$.getScript("http://somedomain.com/somescri...")
```

As mentioned, you're looking for [`eval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval)

```
eval('x = 2');
alert(x)
```